# how do I send a value of my class to the controller

Tags: laravel

how do I send a value $msg of my class to the controller?
the $ msg variable would be the error message that the class would return and wanted to pass from the class to the controller

```
{
function GenerateMbWay($values)
    {


            if($estado=='000'){
                $NewMbWay = new pagamentos_mbway();
                //// .....
                $NewMbWay->save();
            }
            else{
             
        if($estado='020'){
                $msg='error1';
        }
else{
    $msg='erro2';
}


              /// how send value: $msg to use in my controller????


    }
}





public function pay(Request $request) {

$msg=???;   ///value in class
return view()->with('msg', $msg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

public function pay(Request $request) {$msg = array('name' => $request['name'],'email' => $request['email'],'subject' => $request['subject'],'msg' => $request['messages'],);return view('')->with('msg', $msg);}

Comment: basically wanted to do.
"return continue controller -> and use the variable on my comtroller" and then send it with controler to view